# Overlap checking between two lines

Tags: math, geometry, line, intersection

I want to check two lines are intersected or not. I know the algorithm for the how to check intersection between two lines but in my case I have some different issue. For explain my problem I am attaching image here.

[image]

Data that are used to draw :

Line - 1 :

Start Coordinate: -121.001525, 632.378285

End Coordinate: -125.106805, 625.773505

Radius : 1

Line - 2:

Start Coordinate: -121.116355, 632.866595

End Coordinate: -133.183055, 631.490825

Radius : 2.5

How I draw this image :

In the image you can see that center line is in the black color. And draw the outline of image using this radius.

Now come to the point, visually we can see that images are intersecting but line are not intersected. If lines are intersected then we can easily find the line are intersecting or not. But in my case lines are not intersecting but images are intersected so in that how can check that two images are intersected or not?

Any suggestion how to solve this issue?

Comment: How do you check if two segments intersecting?

Comment: I have already developed algorithm to find the intersection between two lines. This is not the issue.

Comment: You need to create some virtual lines - lines that are offset by 1/2 radius perpendicular to each of the real lines. These lines are represented by the straight line-segments that enclose the red areas in your picture. If there is an intersection between any of the real lines or the virtual ones, you have an intersection.

Comment: I can not do this. I have the reason. If I going to create a virtual line then I have to create 4 virtual lines for two lines. Then I have to for all lines that they are intersecting or not that are down the performance that's why I am trying to in this way with the center line.

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty: whether you like it or not, if you want an exact solution to this problem, there is a minimum cost that you cannot avoid. This cost is roughly equal to two line-line intersection operations in a favorable case, to which you have to add two circle-line intersections in other cases.

Comment: Note that all you need to calculate is the (shortest) distance between the two central line segments: your two "lozenge" shapes intersect if and only if that distance is smaller than R1 + R2.

Comment: @MarkDickinson You are right. I have tried with it, but problem is that you can see the image that its satisfy the condition but suppose one line inside of another line then its also satisfy the condition that means its show that two lines are intersect but lines are not intersect because one line inside of another line.

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty: If one (nonempty) subset of the plane is entirely contained in another, those two subsets still "intersect" under the usual definitions. It sounds as though what you really want is to know whether the *boundaries* of your two sets intersect (i.e., the blue lines in your picture).

Comment: But you should also be able to check for containment using distance checks, too: for example, if `R1 <= R2` then Line 1 is entirely contained in Line 2 if and only if both endpoints of Line 1 are within distance `R2 - R1` of  Line 2.

Comment: @MarkDickinson second comment is not clear means the using distance checking. If you don't mind then could you explain it in details?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want to check intersection of two stadium shapes (two half disks and a rectangle), which correspond to given distances to two line segments.

To simplify the problem, you can first reduce `R1` to zero while increasing `R2` to `R=R2+R1`. Then you need to check for intersection of a line segment with a stadium shape.

Rotate and translate all endpoints so that the start point and the endpoint of the stadium shape come to the origin `(0, 0)` and the point `(L, 0)` on the X axis.

Let P0 and P1 be the endpoints of the line segment. The parametric equation is

```
P = (1-u) P0 + u P1,
```

with `0≤u≤1`.

You check intersection with the rectangle by assessing the compatibility of the linear inequations

```
0≤Px=(1-u)P0x+uP1x≤L, -R≤Py=(1-u)P0y+uP1≤R, 0≤u≤1.
```

These three relations establish each a bracketing of `u` and it suffices to check that the three bracketings are compatible.

Then you need to check intersection with the two (half-)circles.

For the circle at the origin, we must have

```
Px²+Py²=((1-u)P0x+uP1x)²+((1-u)P0y+uP1)²≤R², 0≤u≤1.
```

The first relation is a quadratic inequation that you can easily solve by finding the roots and it yields a bracketing of `u`. Then check that the two bracketings are compatible.

The test for the other circle is very similar, just translate the center.

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly check if two segments inflated by radius r intersect by checking if the distance from one segment to another is less than the combined radius r of each segment.
So in your case, shape 1 intersects shape 2 if the distance from segment 1 to segment 2 is less than radius 1 + radius 2.
Of course by doing this you don't know exactly where they did intersect each other, but you know they did.

Answer (score 0):

Many years belated, but just in the case someone is reaching this topic with the same issue.

A classical algorithm for spherocylinders in 3D is the one developed by Vega and Lago.

A fast algorithm to evaluate the shortest distance between rods.
C Vega, S Lago - Computers & chemistry, 1994.
https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-8485(94)80023-5

You can easily find this algorithm already implemented in C and Fortran. The reduction to 2D is straightforward.